# Is there a way to log auto generated messages on Python console?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using pandas to load a csv file that has few bad lines. This means that  in few lines there are some extra commas and that is why pandas is not able to load it. Which is fine by me. I'm using `error_bad_lines=False` to ignore those lines. When those bad lines are ignored by pandas, it shows a message like this on console:

```
b'Skipping line 3: expected 3 fields, saw 4\n
```

What I want is to be able to load the data but log this skipping line number in a log file. I went throught a lot of tutorials on logging but couldn't find a way to log this auto generated message when pandas skip a line number while loading the data.

This is the simple piece of code I'm using to load a file.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def main():
    filename = "test_data3.csv"
    data= pd.read_csv(filename,error_bad_lines=False)
    print(data.head())


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the sample data I'm using

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
a,3,g4
b,4,s5,r
c,5,p9
f,6,v4,7
x,65,h5
```

as you can see line number 2 and 4 should be skipped. But it needs to be recorded in a log file.

Comment: If pandas is using python logging for its messages, then you can configure the default logger. If it's not, you'll have to redirect stdout or stderr (whichever one the error is coming out on) to a file.

Comment: Thanks @GaryO I'm new to Python, can you please share any link where I can learn more about stdout or stderr in the context of logging?

Comment: Are you running it in Linux?

Comment: @DamianLattenero no I'm running it in Windows.

Comment: stdout/stderr are shell concepts, not particular to python. So when you're running `python` you can redirect the stdout to a file like this: `python myprog.py args > /tmp/output.log` and if you want to redirect stderr as well you can do `python myprog.py args >& /tmp/output.log`. But when you do that, you won't see the output. If you're doing interactive work, that's not a good solution for you.

Comment: Is it interactive or batch?

Comment: @GaryO many thanks for the input. I would actually like to see the messages on console as well as log the skipping record in a log file.

Comment: The best way to approach it then is to see how pandas is outputting that error. (Pandas is open source, you can get a copy and search for that error string.) If it's using python logging, you're in luck. If not, post back here with how it's printing the error. If you look around near that code in pandas you might also find ways to redirect or handle it. Worst case you can always "monkey-patch" that function, but that's not usually recommended unless you run out of options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a context manager to temporarily intercept calls to `sys.stderr.write` and write the messages to a file:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

class CaptureErrors:
    def __init__(self, stderr, output_name):
        self.stderr = stderr
        self.output_name = output_name
        self.output_file = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.output_file = open(self.output_name, "w")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if self.output_file:
            self.output_file.close()
        sys.stderr = self.stderr

    def write(self, message):
        self.stderr.write(message)
        self.output_file.write(message)

def main():
    filename = "test_data3.csv"
    with CaptureErrors(sys.stderr, 'error.txt') as sys.stderr:
        data = pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False)
    print(data.head())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

If this isn't what you are looking for, you may need to add more information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redirect the output into a file doubg:

```
python script.py > out.txt
```

Comment: thanks for your message. I can see this message in the console: b'Skipping line 3: expected 3 fields, saw 4\nSkipping line 5: expected 3 fields, saw 4\n'

but how can I save this message in a log file?

Comment: @vik2426 I edited the question let me know if it works for you